# how to install requirements.txt file in python using pip

Tags: python-3.7

when iam trying to install the requirements.txt file by using pip in command prompt iam getting an error like this

pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to path where requirement.txt is saved.

```
cd path (change to directory)
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the path, permissions and exact errors

Comment: For Which folder I need to add the path like,lib or scripts

Comment: installation is happening in the current folder path but not in the sub folders