# Why am I getting a ERNO fileNotFoundException, when the file is in the same folder as the .ipynb notebook?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install dependencies via a `requirements.txt` file.
But I'm running into an error where the file is not found (I'm using Google Collab).

```
!pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

I obtain this error:

> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

But they are both in the same folder

I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784717/how-to-install-requirements-txt-file-in-python-using-pip).

Comment: `!pwd` ? `!ls` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a Google Collab thing, but all I had to do to fix this was to make sure the path pointed to the folder all the files were in [even though the ipynb file was in the same folder as the requirements.txt]: example:

```
cd '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/name/name_of_folder_with_all_files'
```